# Controlar que los datos de un fichero CSV cambian e imprimir el error - Python

Tags: python, archivo

Tengo que realizar un fichero en Python que controle un fichero *".csv"*, y si algún parámetro cambia, indicar qué valor ha cambiado, y si cuadra con la salida esperada.

```
ELEMENTO1,1,1,0,-1,0,-1
```

Cuando cambia una columna sería:

```
ELEMENTO1,1,1,0,-1,1,0
```

Tendría que pasarlo por un código que busque el valor cambiado y lo compare para ver si el valor es `0,1-1` y dar un mensaje diferente (`0:Ok, 1:Pendiente, -1:ERROR`).

Comment: Échale un ojo a watchdog https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer?

Comment: No se como empezar por ejemplo a vigilar ese fichero .csv. No me parece sencillo estar vigilando un fichero. Cuando cambien debería imprimir todo el fichero de nuevo. He escrito esto de momento para intentar monitorizar en tiempo real pero no consigo que funcione:

#Monitorizamos continuamente
outAnterior = ""
while(1):
 fechahora = "" + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ","
 out = ""
 for i in listaRegistros:
  try:
   s = leer(client,i)
   out = out + s + ","
  except:
   out = out + "-1,"
 if(out != outAnterior):
  print (fechahora + out)
 outAnterior = out

Answer (score 1):

esto es mas facil hacerlo con los Dataframes de la libreria panda, te dejo un ejemplo de lo que haría yo:

```
#Importamos las librerias correspondientes,
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Esto lo he tenido que hacer para que lea desde una variable que sea un string, sino usar pd.from_csv(path_del_fichero)
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
# He añadido la primera fila como nombre de columnas, para luego saber la diferencia en que columna esta
TESTDATA=StringIO(
    """header,1,2,3,4,5,6
    ELEMENTO1,1,1,0,-1,0,-1""")
TESTDATA2=StringIO(
    """header,1,2,3,4,5,6
    ELEMENTO1,1,1,0,-1,0,1""")

# Construimos los dos dataframes
df1 = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA2, header=0)

# Comparamos la diferencia
difference_locations = np.where(df1 != df2)
changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]

changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]
df = pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to}, index=changed.index)

# Devolvemos un diccionario con las diferencias:
df.to_dict()

# Esto devolvería algo asi, que viene a decir que en la columna '6' pasa de(from) -1 a(to) 1.
{'from': {(0, '6'): -1}, 'to': {(0, '6'): 1}}
```